# DO Button: convert databin entry from String to Reals

Tags: dataset, interoperability, internet, webservices

I am learning to use the Wolfram databins and DO Button and DO Note apps for a personal project.

The sample code I am using as the Recipe is:

```
location={ {{Latitude}},{{Longitude}}}
```

Now, when I call the data from the databin:

```
In= Values[Databin[bin, 1]]["location"]
Out= {"{ 51.50690466636,-0.194158124029808}"}
```

The Head of this result is a List containing a String. What I would like is either a List containing a List of Reals **or** a a List containing a GeoPosition. At the moment I solve this with writing in my notebook:

```
ToExpression /@ Values[Databin[bin]]["location"]
```

for the first case and

```
GeoPosition /@ ToExpression /@ Values[Databin[bin, 1]]["location"]
```

which works fine, but somehow it annoys me that the data is stored in the databin (or understood upon import by Mathematica) as a string and not as a list of Reals.

Is there a way to store the data in the databin as a List of Reals (by writing code in the DO Recipe)?